# Mysql: Inserting now() value into column shows error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert now() value into a column but it shows error

```
insert into tbl_offerpriceuser('urgentdate') values(NOW()) where user_id='717'
```

It shows 3 errors

3 errors were found during analysis.

```
A comma or a closing bracket was expected (near "(" at position 55)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 56)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 57)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Syntax is wrong for insert:**

```
insert into tbl_offerpriceuser(urgentdate) values(NOW())
```

`NOW()` function don't have any problem. And there is **no `WHERE` condition**.

See the [Syntax to Insert data](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-insert-query.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There is no where clause in insert statements

```
insert into tbl_offerpriceuser('urgentdate') values(NOW());
```

Answer (score -2):

Thats the correct syntax:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_offerpriceuser(`urgentdate`) values(NOW()) WHERE `user_id`='717'
```